# Bash provide default argument if no arguments passed

Tags: bash

I have a program installed which named `zeus`. It's allow me to run commands like this:

```
zeus parallel_rspec spec/
```

Where `parallel_rspec` is command which is runned by zeus and `spec/` is the directory, which is required by `parallel_rspec` command.

I've made an alias in my `.profile`:

```
alias rsp='zeus parallel_rspec'
```

So, I can run commands like this:

```
rsp spec/ # => equal to `zeus parallel_rspec spec/`
```

But `spec/` directory is common (95% cases). How can I make my `rsp` alias pass `spec/` folder argument by default (if I'm not passed something another, like `spec/blablabla`)?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:ruby], [tag:rspec], [tag:zeus], or [tag:ubuntu]? It looks like a simple [tag:bash] question to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a function instead:

```
function rsp {
  [ -z "$1" ] && zeus parallel_rspec spec/ || zeus parallel_rspec "$1"
}
```

You can add it to your profile or bashrc. If you provide no argument to the function `$1` will be empty so it will use `/spec` as the path, otherwise it will use the argument

Comment: It could be just `rsp() { zeus parallel_rspec "${1:-spec/}" }`.

Comment: @hauleth I think your comment should be an answer so i can upvote it.

Answer (score 18):

Bash has syntax for default value of variable:

```
${VARNAME:-default}
```

So in your case you need to use function that looks like:

```
rsp() { zeus parallel_rspec "${1:-spec/}" }
```

or if you wanna pass some more options, just in case:

```
rsp() {
  folder="${1:-spec/}"
  shift 1
  zeus parallel_rspec "$folder" "$@"
}
```